# after ssh session : -bash: /bin/ls: no such file or directory

Tags: ssh, command-line, ls

I've logged into my Ubuntu server from work via putty under Windows. Right away I noticed something weird. I could not use the ls command. Got:

`-bash: /bin/ls: no such file or directory`

I didn't pay much attention, I thought it was a putty thing.

Tonight I've logged from home via ssh under Ubuntu and I get the same problem on my server!

Not only that but other commands like `find` give me the same message.

I've also noticed that all colours are gone in the prompt.

If I echo PATH, I get :

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

to replace `ls`I can use `dir`and it works, but that's only a temporary workaround.

Also I've tried:

`ldd /bin/ls`

gives me `is not and dynamic executable`

What could be the problem ?

**EDIT**

Oh and running `apt-get update`gives me:

W: Failed to fetch  http://ftp.free.fr/mirrors/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving  « ftp.free.fr:http » (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

Comment: Did you fixed it? Have you tried `type ls` ?